# Need explaination on two different approach to find factorial

Tags: java

I am a beginner.I already learned C. But now Java is seeming difficult to me. As in C programming my approach was simple , when I looked at Book's programs for simple task such as Factorial, its given very complex programs like below -

```
class Factorial {
    // this is a recursive method
    int fact(int n) {
        int result;
        if(n==1) return 1;
        result = fact(n-1) * n;
        return result;
    }
}
class Recursion {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Factorial f = new Factorial();
        System.out.println("Factorial of 3 is " + f.fact(3));
        System.out.println("Factorial of 4 is " + f.fact(4));
        System.out.println("Factorial of 5 is " + f.fact(5));
    }
}
```

Instead, when I made my own program (given below) keeping it simple , it also worked and was easy. Can anyone tell me what's the difference between two ?

```
public class Simplefacto {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int n = 7;
       int result = 1;
       for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
           result = result * i;
       }
       System.out.println("The factorial of 7 is " + result);
   }
}
```

also can anyone tell me what is java EE and java SE ?

Comment: First one is recursive approach and second one one is iterative.

Comment: C has also recursion. Arguably, faculty is not an enlightening example for demonstrating it.

Comment: Start from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html

Comment: It's custom in Java to isolate functionality from the `main` function. This is why the `Factorial` class was created: its purpose is to compute a factorial for a number given. I agree, for such simple requests it's a lot of overhead, but for more complex programs, this approach, separating different functionalities from one another, is desirable.

Comment: You don't calc fac(3),fac(4) nor fac(5) in your version.

Comment: Java is object oriented, C not! You are using Object on the first block and a simple main on the second block. JAVA SE means JAVA, JAVA EE means java + extension fo enterprise applications.

Comment: this is very dumb method for calculating factorial. and even making it tail-recursive won't help because Java and JVM don't do TCO.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is that of recursion. Which is not always fast and easy. (and usually leads to StackOverflowError, if you are not careful). The second approach is that of a normal for loop. Interstingly, both approaches are valid even in "C".

I think you should not compare Java programs with C programs. Both languages were designed for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main differences between those programs:

- Program 1 uses recursion
- Program 2 uses the imperative approach
- Program 1 uses a class where all program logic is encapsuled
- Program 2 has all the logic "like the good old C programs" in one method

Comment: in c programs also, `inline` code is not suggested unless its very minimal, right? :) you should group logics in `functions` wherever possible

Comment: @dreamer - yes. It is not suggested. But what has that gotto do with the above answer?

Comment: he mentions "like the good old C programs" which contains all logic in one method

Answer (score 0):

The first method is Recursive. This means that the method makes calls to itself and the idea behind this is that recursion (when used appropriately) can yield extremely clean code, much like your `factorial` method. Formatted correctly is should look more like:

```
private int factorial(int n) {
    if(n==1) return n;

    return fact(n-1) * n;
}
```

So that's a factorial calculator in two lines, which is extremely clean and short. The problem is that you can run into problems for large values of `n`. Namely, the infamous `StackOverflowError`.

The second method is what is known as iterative. Iterative methods usually involve some form of a loop, and are the other option to recursion. The advantage is that they make quite readable and easy to follow code, even if it is somewhat more verbose and lengthy. This code is more robust and won't fall over for large values of `n`, unless `n! > Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are adding a behavior that can be reused in `multiple behaviors` or `main()` while in the second case, you are putting `inline` code thats not reusable. The other difference is the `recursion vs iteration`. `fact()` is based on recursion while the `inline` code in `main()` is achieving the same thing using `iteration`